# insight on building a jpeg map for a multiplayer game

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps

im currently working on a simulation game,app that is going to be built in `html5` `JavaScript` and a `php` server back-end (small scale), and i will use `phone-gap` or `cordova` to compile for android and im currently at a point in development where i need some sort of map solution i kinda like the idea of a google-maps type map with spots on the map a user would be able to zoom in on and be able to interact with, think  grand theft auto map, meets Google maps i wanna use tool tips provided by bootstrap for the interactions and a custom desgined map im designing in Photoshop right now .... thanks in advance for your answers.

my question is how would i go about turning a jpeg image of custom-map to something that can be scaled up and down, and adding some sort of grid solution that has x-y coordinates  that JavaScript can access 
[image: the curent map im desinging now]

Comment: There is not actually a question in all that text you provided.

Comment: @thatidiotguy my apologizes my question is how would i go about turning a jpeg image of custom-map to something that can be scaled up and down, and adding some sort of grid solution that has x-y coordinates  that JavaScript can access

Comment: You can covert the files to kml/kmz file and use it as a layer in Google Maps. This is one way to do (https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/geotagsimple) it but there are various other ways out there.